# Check multiple conditions in a string and return binary indicator

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to filter and group the data of my `df` according to the character in the `comment_1` and `comment_2` and give the indicator `0` or `1` as a final result. However, there are some rules that come together with the filter. The rules are:

1. If the `comment_1` of the row consists of `apple` and the `comment_2` of the row consists of `apple` as
   well, then use `price_1` minus `price_2`. If the number after subtraction is greater than 20, then the
   `result` will be `1`, if less than 20, then the `result` will be `0`
2. If the `comment_1` of the row consists of `orange` and `comment_2` consists of `apple` / the
   `comment_1` consist of `apple` and `comment_2` consist of `orange`, then also use `price_1` minus
   `price_2`. If the number after sbutraction is greater than 10, then the `result` wil be `1` otherwise
   the `result` will be `0`.

Take note that the it doesn't matter is Apple or apple, Orange or orange, so the code should take capital letter into consideration as well.

For example:

1. 1st row of the data is `apple (comment_1)` to `Apple (comment_2)`, and the result of `price_1` minus `price_2` is 13 which is smaller than 20, hence the `result` will be shown as `0`.
2. 2nd row of the data is orange (comment_1) `to Apple (comment_2)` and the result is `11` after minus `price_1` with `price_2`, since 11 is greater than 10, so the final `result` will be shown as `1`.
3. Since the 4th row `price_1` `-` `price_2` `= 2` which is smaller than 10, so the result is `0`.

I attached my df as below and the final column result is the final answer.

```
price_1 <- c(25, 33, 54, 24)
price_2 <- c(12, 22, 11, 22)
itemid <- c(22203, 44412,55364, 552115)
itembds <- as.integer(c("", 21344, "", ""))
comment_1 <- c("The apple is expensive", "The orange is sweet", "The Apple is nice", "the apple is not nice")
comment_2 <- c("23 The Apple was beside me", "The Apple was left behind", "The apple had rotten", "the Orange should be fine" )
result <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)

df <- data.frame(price_1, price_2, itemid, itembds, comment_1, comment_2, result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple if-else statement. Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `stringr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(price_a = if_else(str_detect(comment_1, "[Aa]pple") & 
                              str_detect(comment_2, "[Aa]pple"), price_1 - price_2, 0),
              price_o = if_else(str_detect(comment_1, "[Oo]range") &
                                  str_detect(comment_2, "[Aa]pple"), price_1 - price_2, 0),
              price_o = if_else(str_detect(comment_1, "[Aa]pple") &
                                  str_detect(comment_2, "[Oo]range"), price_1 - price_2, price_o),
              res_actual = if_else(price_o > 10, 1, 0),
              res_actual = if_else(price_a > 20, 1, res_actual)) %>% 
  select(-price_o, -price_a)
```

```
price_1 price_2 itemid itembds              comment_1                  comment_2 result res_actual
1      25      12  22203      NA The apple is expensive 23 The Apple was beside me      0          0
2      33      22  44412   21344    The orange is sweet  The Apple was left behind      1          1
3      54      11  55364      NA      The Apple is nice       The apple had rotten      1          1
4      24      22 552115      NA  the apple is not nice  the Orange should be fine      0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `case_when` with `grepl` to test for various conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(result = case_when(
             grepl('apple', comment_1, ignore.case = TRUE) &
             grepl('apple', comment_2, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ +(price_1 - price_2 > 20), 
             grepl('orange', comment_1, ignore.case = TRUE) &
             grepl('apple', comment_2, ignore.case = TRUE) |
             grepl('apple', comment_1, ignore.case = TRUE) &
             grepl('orange', comment_2, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ +(price_1 - price_2 > 10)))


#  price_1 price_2 itemid itembds              comment_1                  comment_2 result
#1      25      12  22203      NA The apple is expensive 23 The Apple was beside me      0
#2      33      22  44412   21344    The orange is sweet  The Apple was left behind      1
#3      54      11  55364      NA      The Apple is nice       The apple had rotten      1
#4      24      22 552115      NA  the apple is not nice  the Orange should be fine      0
```